# Unable to load underlying frameworks with xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

```
<unknown>:0: error: missing required modules: 'Alamofire', 'ObjectMapper'
Command MergeSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code
```

My project work well with xcode 9 , once updated to modern swift 4.2 and everything seem to work (latest alamo , latest obj mapper) . My only problem is i cant connect underlying modules to the project and test classes.  Anything to solve ?

Comment: how did you add AlamoFire?  Cocoapods?  If so, did you try doing a `pod update` in the directory that contains your Podfile?

Comment: Try all the usual, comman+shift+k to clean the build, close Xcode, go to /Users/YourUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/ and delete the DerivedData folder, pod update as Michael suggested and build again